# Issue with Spring Integration Aggregator group-timeout value

Tags: spring-integration

We are using Spring Integration 4.2.3 Aggregator component and defined group-timeout and expecting the group to be timed out within the given timeout value while adding messages to the group & release size criteria is not met.

But we are seeing different results, when we input heavy load to the service the aggregator is waiting on all messages to be added to the group rather than expiring the group when the timeout reached.

Is there any way to override the aggregator functionality to look at the first message rather than last message when timing out group.

Answer (score 3):

Well, actually you can do what you need even now. Using the same `group-timeout-expression`. But you have to consult the `#root` object of the evaluation context which is exactly what you need - `MessageGroup`. With that you can call one of for your purpose:

```
/**
 * @return the timestamp (milliseconds since epoch) associated with the creation of this group
 */
long getTimestamp();

/**
 * @return the timestamp (milliseconds since epoch) associated with the time this group was last updated
 */
long getLastModified();
```

Therefore an expression for your original request might be like:

```
group-timeout-expression="timestamp + 10000 - T(System).currentTimeMillis()"
```

And we get that adjusted timeout which will be applied to scheduled task with the value like: `new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + groupTimeout));`.

Comment: Hi Artem,I still can't get it working, this is what I want to achieve. I want a group to be timed out after let's say 10 secs after the first message in it arrives. How do I achieve this with above group-timeout-expression?

Comment: M-m-m. I might be wrong. Let's try this: `timestamp + 10sec - now`. The reason to do this because the schedule is done based on `now` + calculated timeout. So, I suggest to make it based on the group `timestamp` property. See my edited version for the `group-timeout-expression`

Comment: Artem, We decided to use messagestorereaper rather than group-timeout-expression, is there anyway that we can configure reaper to expire different groups in different times?

Comment: No, there is no. It one action per store. So, you can configure different reapers for different store. But at the same time you have to configure different aggregators for those stores where each aggregator will form its own independent groups. What’s wrong with the expression though?

Comment: As far as my understanding the expression you provided will act as reaper? I dont need any externel reaper ? Also the group time expression will be again dependent on new message coming in ?

Comment: Correct, you don’t need anything else. Well, it is like : you have `10` as a group start timeout. You want to expire it in `10` seconds therefore your wish is like `10+10`. But aggregator calculate the time in the future relatively to `now`. So, to get the same `20` let’s say from the `now == 17` we should do: `10 + 10 - 17` and the result of this evaluation will be use for the time in future - `17 + 3`. And this algorithm doesn’t depend on new messages. Right, we recalculate to the same `20` on each message, but that is how expire works without reaper

Answer (score 0):

No; the timeout is currently based on the arrival of the last message only.

If you use a `MessageGroupStoreReaper` instead, the time is based on the group creation by default, but that can be changed by setting the group store's `timeoutOnIdle` to true.

If your group is not timing out at all, perhaps the thread pool in the default `taskScheduler` is exhausted - it only has 10 threads by default.

You can increase the pool size or inject a dedicated scheduler into the aggregator.

Comment: Thanks Gary for answering my question. May I know what is this TimeoutCountSequenceSizeReleaseStrategy for? And also can I set up MessageGroupStoreReaper only for specific group?

Comment: The problem is our application can form 3 different groups but will setting up MessageGroupStoreReaper cause all groups to timeout at a time?

Comment: The `TimeoutCountSequenceSizeReleaseStrategy` is passive and has a good JavaDocs for explanation how it works. I guess it doesn't work for you properly because it looks like you need to reap from time to time.

Comment: Thanks Artem, I understand that Reaper is a soultion for me but I don't want to expire all the groups with the reaper, can I only expire a specific group periodically or set up dynamic value based on groupKey or groupID?

Comment: I think you don't need reaper. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

we debugged the issue with your `group-timeout-expression(timestamp + 20000 - T(System).currentTimeMillis())`  and found out that the expression is evaluating to a negative value after messaged keep flowing in thus causing the group never getting released.

The code block where the issue is in `AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler.java`

[image]

Once we removed the condition of "`groupTimeout >= 0`", now the group is getting expired because of the else block. The code is now behaving like how we expected.

Could you let me know why you are not forcing the group to be `timedoout` when it reaches negative value?

Comment: Hi, I was reading this entry and we are interested to know how the value for the timeout as aforementioned evaluated to a negative value. We are also using the Aggregator to gather messages that arrived in a specified time frame. As you're telling the conditional clause you pointed out is problematic, we would like to know under what circumstance did this happen? If MessageGroup's timestamp + timeout evaluates to some value that is less than System.currentTimeMillis, then something is not consistent?

Comment: Please, consider to edit your question if you have such an information instead. Also notify us in the comments related to our posts. Otherwise we don't know about your posts here. Right, SO might not be so useful for such a conversion, but that's different story.

Comment: Anyway I think you have a point about the negative value and definitely should reconsider such a logic. Please, raise a JIRA on the matter and we together will think about that.